# Comparing list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

So, i wanna check if there are some words that a list A and a dictionary B has in common. I then wanna check if the sum of the values of the common words(keys) are higher than 10. I wanna be able to do this in a simple way.

Example (not working properly):

```
A = ['a','b','c','e']
B = {'a': 12, 'b': 8, 'c':3,'d':15}

TheSum = 0
for key,value in B.items():
    if key in A:
        TheSum += int(value)
        if TheSum > 10:
            print ("The sum of the values are higher than 10 and the words incommon are:")
            print (key,"=", value,"points")
        else:
            print ("Nothing in common")
```

**I want it to print:**

The sum of the values are higher than 10 and the words incommon are:

a = 12 points

b = 8 points

c = 3 points

I hope that my problem is understandable. I think that it gets too messy with all the for- and if-statments.

Comment: In which langage do you work? Your pseudo code looks nice, not particulary messy, why do you think that? The only thing I see is to invert the loops. Loop first throught your list and then search the dictionary, that what dictionary are made for.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `set` and then a generator expression.  Probably easier to show.  First we get the common elements:

```
>>> A = ['a','b','c','e']
>>> B = {'a': 12, 'b': 8, 'c':3,'d':15}
>>> set(A).intersection(B)
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

And then we can take the sum of the values of B associated with these keys:

```
>>> common = set(A).intersection(B)
>>> sum(B[k] for k in common)
23
```

And then print something if this is > 10.

Right now, you're looping over every key, value pair in B (okay), and then checking to see if the key is in A (which will work but will be slow, because in order to test membership in a list you have to scan over the elements.)  If the key is in A, you then accumulate TheSum.  That part actually works.

But you're printing every key/value pair after the cumulative sum is > 10, which I don't think is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

To test if the sum of the values in `B` with keys in `A` is larger than 10:

```
if sum(B[k] for k in A if k in B):
    print("sum higher than 10")
else:
    print("sum lower than 10")
```

If you want a list of elements of `A` which are keys in `B`, you get it from `[k for k in A if k in B]`.